# How to view aspect affected Java classes in IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: java, spring, ide, intellij-idea, aspectj

Is there some way to see the aspect affected (advised) Java methods in IntelliJ IDEA?

Like [XRef](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/xref/) in Eclipse?

[image: XRef]

**Edited:**

@Xiujun_Ma showed the feature exists, but I don't know what is not working.
I'm using the libs and the facets on the project.

**Libs:**

[image: libs]

**Facets:**

[image: Facets]

Comment: How that could be affected, an example?

Comment: The Cross References view (also known as "XRef") is an extensible Eclipse tool that can be used to show information relating to Java elements shown in the editor or outline view. It is used in AJDT to show AspectJ crosscutting information, such as when a Java method is affected by advice.

Answer (score 4):

In your aspect class you will see like this:
[image]

click the ball after line number (navigate to advised methods),

then, you will see aspect affected methods.

Comment: Do I need to activate some configuration? I have the default configuration on Intellij IDEA 12 and this is not being showed.

Comment: I have tried, put org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect annotation on your class, and org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around on your method with right expression, this symbol will appear.BTW, I imported aspectjweaver 1.7.1 with maven.

Comment: You should check 'AspectJ support' plugin && 'Spring AOP and @AspectJ' plugin in plugin list.

Comment: I'm doing the same, but no annotations. I'm using Aspectj .aj files. All plugins are ok by default and the libs are imported. Do you know what is the feature name on Intellij?

Comment: This feature really doesn't work on .aj file, I don't know is it a bug, I will continue to focus on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is shown as you can see from @XiujunMa answer. It also works in 11.1.3. Used to navigate to the transaction affected methods in Spring.

> To be able to use the AspectJ support in IntelliJ IDEA, you have to
>   make sure that the following plugins are enabled:
>
> ```
> Spring-AOP and @AspectJ Support.
> AspectJ Support.
> ```
>
> In addition to that, you should also create a library for
>   aspectjrt.jar.

You probably need to use `<aop:config>` in the spring configuration to define `<aop:pointcut`. Then use `<aop:advisor` to map that pointcut and advice reference. You could also put the `<aop:aspect` there.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for, but in IDEA 12 seems to be not showing here with default configuration.

Comment: It will show you if you add `<tx:annotation-driven` to your config.

Comment: What config file? I'm not using annotation. I'm using .aj files of AspectJ, not Spring Aspects.

Comment: Then you could use AspectJ facet to your module.

Comment: Already using, this project is working with maven 3 and eclipse. I imported the aspectj-weaver and the aspects are being compiled without errors. How is the feature name of this on Intellij?

Comment: I did a talk about facet in IDEA. Did you see that facet there, are you running ultimate version?

Comment: Yes, the ultimate 12 version.  https://www.evernote.com/shard/s163/sh/1250be2f-440f-4df3-affa-ffb850c6e751/93f0f6c75e325ea5ed15d7f9cbbc8588

Comment: There are the libs https://www.evernote.com/shard/s163/sh/9775ce20-ac93-4a44-b71b-2241b0eeafcd/e45834246eca88b0a8401b90497b0bab